# Now.js + Express -> Disconnect issue

Tags: security, node.js, express, nowjs-sockets, poker

this is a question to all the Node Gurus out there:

I'm new using NowJs with Express and i'm building a poker site. The main problem that I have is :

When a User creates a game, opens a new window and close it.
When closing this second window the Disconnect event is triggered disconnecting the user from the first window

How can I avoid this issue? There's gotta be a workaround
Also, I'm I doing right to use NodeJs and Express as base to a website that will store credit card information? If not, what is the best way to build a poker site?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Make sure you contact a lawyer before building the site.

Answer (score 0):

Don't load NowJS in the second window. Communicate with the server from the main window, accessing its functions from the second window using `window.opener.myFunction()`.